# Change background-color of element inside container-fluid

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, containers, background-color

How can I change the background color of my h3 element which is nested within a container-fluid element?

I've set a background color for the whole container fluid but I'd like the h3 element to have a different background-color.  I imagine the h3 is underneath the container-fluid but I can't work out how to change the hierarchy.

Here's my html:

```
<section class="container-fluid" id="portfolio">

<h3 id="portfolio-title">PORTFOLIO</h3>
```

And the CSS:

```
.container-fluid {
padding: 0 !important;
}

#portfolio-title {
background-color: #2E3747;
}

#portfolio {
background-color: #EFF0F0;
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this CSS

```
#portfolio {
background-color: #EFF0F0;
}

#portfolio #portfolio-title {
background-color: #2E3747 !important;
}
```

I've just moved the portfolio up then h3 to down and made it important

Comment: Nice! It worked but I don't understand it haha... Why does #portfolio need to be included in the second CSS entry?

Comment: #portfolio isn't necessary but it shows that it is a parent of #portfolio-title so it is only going to target title inside #portfolio, moving #portfolio up and #title down was actually helped because browser renders CSS line by line.

Answer (score 2):

Let's try this code

```
#porfolio:not(#portfolio-title) {
     background-color: #EFF0F0;
}



#portfolio-title {
     background-color: #2E3747;
}
```

Select `.container-fluid` but not `porfolio-title`.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has nothing wrong in it..this is the way to go

**working snippet**

```css
.container-fluid {
padding: 0 !important;
}

#portfolio-title {
background-color: blue;
color: red;
}

#portfolio {
background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<section class="container-fluid" id="portfolio">

<h3 id="portfolio-title">PORTFOLIO</h3>
```